# How to handle translation for texts inside a .js of a WP theme

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a WordPress application and usually I use the PHP function `<?php _e('foo', 'bar') ?>` when I need to echo something that needs to be translated. But, right now I am implementing a new feature and in my `.js` file I have something like

```
var confirmation = confirm("Are you sure you want to quit"); 
if(confirmation){
 ... 
}
```

The problem with the above code is that I can't use the PHP function `_e()` to translate it since this a JS script.

Is there anyway to enable translation for texts echoed in JS?

#### Update

I am adding an update, since the questions given are generic whereas I am searching for a solution that can solve my issue.

I am working on WP project that was built by someone before. I am supposed to only add a translation to codes that exist in js file called `functions.js` path: `C:\Users\meskerem\foo.com\wp-content\themes\foo\assets\scripts\functions.js` let's assume the following code exists inside the function.

```
var confirmation = confirm("Are you sure you want to quit"); 
if(confirmation){
 ... 
}
```

Now the objective is make that English sentence translatable. The above js code is executed when a button inside this file is clicked.
`C:\Users\meskerem\foo.com\wp-content\plugins\wp-jobhunt\templates\dashboards\candidate\templates_ajax_functions.php`

The HTML code that triggers the translation is as simple as:

```
<h1> <?= _e('good morning', 'jobhunt') ?> </h1>
<div> <i class='icon-trash' onclick="askConfirmation()"> x </i> </div>
```

So, the script is simple but translating is where I have some issues.

Comment: Your `confirm("text")` should probably be inside the if-statement (`if(confirm("text")) { /*code*/ }`). I cannot help with the rest, as I have little to no wordpress knowledge.

Comment: @Pyromonk No, otherwise the if statement would never be triggered.

Comment: Actually the statement in the if statement should be `if(confirmation)` since that is the variable that holds the boolean that is returned by the confim() function.

Comment: @PhillHealey, https://jsfiddle.net/v7yr1hys/

Comment: @Pyromonk Ah, your message reads as in "inside the if-statement", meaning if the 'if' condition is met. Whereas you meant make it part of the clause itself. eg `if(confirm){var confirmation = confirm("Are you sure you want to quit"); }`

Comment: @PhillHealey, you are right, I apologise. That means I should go to bed.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say `if(confirmation){}`

Comment: no probs @Pyromonk a fiddle is always good for clearing things up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In word press you have to pass translation array to respective java script.

for example,

if you are en queue script like below from function.php file,

```
wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps,$ver,$in_footer );
```

you have to add translation from function file to perticular js by use his handle inside wp_localize_script();

```
  e.g. wp_enqueue_script( 'your-handle', $src, $deps,$ver,$in_footer );

  $translation_array = array('messagekey' => __('Are you sure you want to quit', foo');                             );
  wp_localize_script('your-handle', 'langvars', $translation_array);
```

**In your case**

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'cs_functions_js', plugins_url('/assets/scripts/functions.js', __FILE__ ), '', '', true );

just add below code after above code.

$translation_array = array('messagekey' => __('Are you sure you want to quit', foo');                                );
  wp_localize_script('cs_functions_js', 'langvars', $translation_array);
```

Then you can access translation in js like,

```
var confirmboxmessage = langvars.messagekey;
var confirmation = confirm(langvars.messagekey);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143465/discussion-on-answer-by-ash-patel-how-to-handle-translation-for-texts-inside-a).

Answer (score 8):

You should use the [wp_localize_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) function, which was added to WordPress for this very reason.

Try with something like this:

```
wp_localize_script( $handle, $name, $data );
```

Example

```
<?php

// Register the script
wp_register_script( 'some_handle', '<ENTER YOUR SCRIPT PATH HERE>' );

// Localize the script with new data
$translation_array = array(
    'some_string' => __( 'Some string to translate', 'plugin-domain' ),
    'a_value' => '10'
);
wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'object_name', $translation_array );

// Enqueued script with localized data.
wp_enqueue_script( 'some_handle' );
```

You can access the variables in JavaScript as follows:

```
<script>
// alerts 'Some string to translate'
alert( object_name.some_string);
</script>
```

Note: The data in the resulting JavaScript call will be passed as text. If you are trying to pass integers you will need to call the JavaScript parseInt() function.

```
<script>
// Call a function that needs an int.
FinalZoom = map.getBoundsZoomLevel( bounds ) - parseInt( object_name.a_value, 10 ); 
</script>
```

Comment: Do I need to add `path/to/myscript.js` file in my app, or can I use the one I already have for it?

Comment: No, you use the path to your file. The one given is just an example to show that you need to use your own path. Please accept my answer as this is the correct way to go about doing what you need. See the link I posted to the WordPress codex for confirmation.

Comment: can you update your answer so I can accept and vote? Currently it does not work for me

Comment: btw: for the part you say `"// Register the script
wp_register_script( 'some_handle', 'path/to/myscript.js' );"` I am sure `myscript.js` is registered already. It is part of a jobhunt plugin, there are already tons of scripts that were working before I decided to add a small feature into it. So, do I still need to add this?

Comment: P.s. My answer is the correct one, it's not necessary for me to spell out exactly how you should do something in your specific set of circumstances. That is for you to figure out, however I am doing my best and will continue to do so within reason.

Comment: I meant the script where I want to show translations from is already part of the wordpress theme and plugin. But thanks anyway

Comment: Ah sorry, I understand now. You will need to either change the way that the script file is loaded -so that it uses the method given above- or take out the relevant code and put that in a new .js file that is loaded via the method above. Without doing this, the script will always be loaded outside of WordPress's direct control meaning that translations will not be activated. Removing your code is the best method since it would otherwise get overwritten if the theme was updated.

Comment: +1 . creating a new js file and registering it will complicate things as I don't know how that works and will likely waste many hours instead of getting this  thing working and be done with it. So far I am have added so many working features on top of the existing theme, this translation thing is the only thing stopping me. I get `Notice: wp_register_script was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks.` error. I am adding your code inside a plugin btw: should I add it in theme

Comment: I like to do it the correct way, but this is a prototype app made in India. I will help make a new site Symfony/Drupal .. but right now, the objective is to add this small feature ... which you could have helped me with instead. I am relearning WP from scratch just for this issue. Anyway, I can do it in a week, no problem

Comment: Wow! Glad to know you don't appreciate me volunteering my time and knowledge to help you. Cool, go ahead and do it yourself. SO is here to help people who want to learn, not for volunteers to do everything for you. This PHP work, the fact that it's a WP site is mostly irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the problem correctly, you have a script that is enqueued by a third party plugin or theme, and you want to localize the `window.confirm` box without modifying the original scripts.

**/wp-content/plugins/jobhunt-client-translations/jobhunt-client-translations.php**

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Jobhunt Translations
Author: John Doe
*/

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'translations', plugins_url( '/translations.js', __FILE__ ) );

    // change the translations domain from 'default' to match yours
    // you can also add other translations here in format "message" => "translated message"
    wp_localize_script( 'translations', 'DialogMessages', [ 'Are you sure you want to quit' => __( 'Are you sure you want to quit', 'default' ) ] );

});
```

**/wp-content/plugins/jobhunt-client-translations/translations.js**

```
(function( original ) {
    window.confirm = function( message ) {
        message = DialogMessages[message] || message;
        return original.call( this, message );
    };
})(window.confirm);
```

Create new folder `jobhunt-client-translations` in `/wp-content/plugins/` directory, place inside these the two files, and activate the plugin. 
It will simply override default `window.confirm` dialog without changing any of the original third party files, and without modifying the default behavior of the dialog box except that message will be translated.

The code was tested and it works properly.

Answer (score 2):

maybe this could help

```
function addScript() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'functions', get_template_directory_uri() . 'foo\assets\scripts\functions.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'addScript' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a simple PHP script your JS can call via AJAX which does nothing more than translate a string, (or several strings) sent through HTTP GET and echo it out as the response body (probably with json_encode()).

Then you can create a JS function for making that AJAX call, so calling it could be as simple as calling a JS function

```
var confirmTxt = jstranslate('Are you sure you want to quit?');
```

And using JQuery for example:

```
function jstranslate(string)
{
    translations = $.get('/my-ajax-translate-url',{string: string}, function(e){
        return e.text; // console.log e to double check what to return, this is from memory
    });
}
```

And In PHP

```
// require_once() your _e() function.
$text = _e($_GET['string'], 'jobhunt');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('text' => $text));
exit;
```